# Finding the mode of a series consisting of list elements in Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, series

I am working with a `pd.Series` where each entry is a list. I would like to find the mode of the series, that is, the most common list in this series. I have tried using both [`pandas.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`pandas.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html). However, both of these approaches lead to the following exception being raised:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Here is a simple example of such a series:

```
pd.Series([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [1,2,3]])
```

I am looking for a function that will return `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: How big are your series?

Comment: Not very big - several hundred elements, and the lists are also of several hundred entries. I did not compare the solutions for speed if that's what you're thinking of

Comment: I highly, highly recommend you do. Brevity != performance.

Comment: @COLDSPEED fully agree. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists are not hashable, so you will need to transform your `Series` of `list`s to a `Series` of `tuple`s.

Once you do that, you can use a `Counter` to *quickly* and *efficiently* generate a multi-set of tuples, and then use `Counter.most_common` to extract the most common element (AKA, the `mode`).

```
s = pd.Series([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [1,2,3]])
```

```
from collections import Counter  

c = Counter(tuple(l) for l in s)
list(c.most_common(1)[0][0])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I also dont understand the down vote. It works. I  just took Wen's solution for brevity

Comment: Wasn't me. +1 for this solution.

Comment: Thanks guys. @splinter I don't care about the accepts so much as I care that you learn something useful from this. As long as you did, that's fine by me

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert to `tuple` , then using `mode`

```
pd.Series([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [1,2,3]]).apply(tuple).mode().apply(list)
Out[192]: 
0    [1, 2, 3]
dtype: object
```

Slightly improvement:

```
list(pd.Series([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [1,2,3]]).apply(tuple).mode().iloc[0])
Out[210]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Since two apply is ugly

```
s=pd.Series([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [1,2,3]])
s[s.astype(str)==s.astype(str).mode()[0]].iloc[0]
Out[205]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Beautiful. Just for completion, I would add at the end `.iloc[0]`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes two apply is annoy

Comment: What I find annoying is downvotes without explanation. :(

Comment: @splinter yep that is true : -) since you need the list , and I will recommend my second method :-) should be faster than the first one :-)

Comment: @Wen I reckon your second solution is actually going to be far slower. The second `apply` is fine given that you're unlikely to have many modes.